# Cómo usar PWDENCRYPT y PWDCOMPARE con SQL Sever?

Tags: sql-server

Necesito algun ejemplo para encriptar un campo para contraseña con estas funciones por favor

Comment: ¿Has hecho alguna búsqueda al respecto? ¿Puedes compartir lo que has encontrado, tus intentos y donde no logras que te funcione? Como dice el botoncito del voto para arriba, se espera que la pregunta refleje trabajo de investigación.

Comment: Sí, ya estuve investigando bastente, y necesito que sea con PWDENCRYPT, invetigué en: https://augustohumire.wordpress.com/2009/02/26/como-crear-un-campo-que-tenga-una-contrasena-o-password-en-sql-server/    también https://sqlpsykrest.wordpress.com/2009/02/17/sql-cifrarencriptar-decifrardesencriptar-campos-en-sql2005/

Comment: *Necesito algun ejemplo*: ¿no es eso justamente lo que se encuentra en las páginas que enlazastes?

Comment: El problema es que al ejecutar algnos de esos ejemplos no me funcionan... Me dicen que el campo de contraseña debe tener tipo de datos Varbinary, pero al intentar insertar datos me sale otro error.

Comment: Todos estos son detalles valiosos que deberías incluir en tu pregunta, que reflejan esfuerzo de tu parte, y que serán muy utiles para lectores futuros. Te sugiero que modifiques tu pregunta y que incluyas claramente la información acerca de tus intentos hasta ahora, asi como los errores específicos que resultaron de tus intentos.

Comment: Y no te olvides de especificar la versión de SQL Server que usas. Puede que afecte cuales soluciones están disponibles.

Comment: Ok, está bien. Pero tienen alguna función cualquiera para encriptar el campo. Utilizo SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En SQL Server 2012 o superior, no utilices la vieja función [PWDENCRYPT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd822791.aspx), ya que está marcada como obsoleta y no existirá en futuras versiones de SQL Server.

Utiliza en su lugar la función [HASHBYTES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx), en la que además tienes control sobre el algoritmo hash que se utiliza.

Suponiendo que tienes una tabla de usuarios, en la que una columna está destinada a almacenar el [hash](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funci%C3%B3n_hash) de la contraseña del usuario, llamada `hash_pwd` y declarada de esta manera:

```
create table usuario (
    ulogin varchar(100) not null primary key
  , hash_pwd varbinary(128)
);
```

Insertar un usuario sería algo como:

```
insert into Usuario (ulogin, hash_pwd) values ('juan', HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', '##Contra$en@DeJu@N##'));
```

Veamos qué se ha almacenado:

```
select * from Usuario 

ulogin  hash_pwd
------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
juan    0x03B7107E44A1146AC6DEE3C8065F87F47AC8933C0DA5359248D2B9EA2242B5738CB55606647F579E802A2D664FB59CB3A47EDE8557E89D4B77FC70AEAC594641
```

Un cambio de contraseña, sería algo como:

```
update usuario set hash_pwd = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', '##MiNueV@ContRa$3n@//');
```

Y una comparación para ver si la contraseña introducida es correcta, podría ser:

```
select cast(case when hash_pwd = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', '##MiNueV@ContRa$3n@//') then 1 else 0 end as bit) FlagPwdCorrecto
  from Usuario
 where ulogin = 'juan';

FlagPwdCorrecto
---------------
1

(1 row(s) affected)
```

La consulta anterior devuelve 1 (`True`), mientras la siguiente devuelve 0 (`False`)

```
select cast(case when hash_pwd = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'NoLaSe') then 1 else 0 end as bit) FlagPwdCorrecto
  from Usuario
 where ulogin = 'juan';

FlagPwdCorrecto
---------------
0

(1 row(s) affected)
```